# starting values for nls() to solve singular gradient error in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting, exponential, stat, nls

I am attempting to fit nls() for 520 users to achieve the coefficients of the exponential fitting. The following is a small representation of my data.

```
dput(head(Mfrq.df.2))
structure(list(User.ID = c("37593", "38643", "49433", "60403", 
"70923", "85363"), V1 = c(9L, 3L, 4L, 80L, 19L, 0L), V2 = c(10L, 
0L, 29L, 113L, 21L, 1L), V3 = c(5L, 2L, 17L, 77L, 7L, 2L), V4 = c(2L, 
2L, 16L, 47L, 4L, 3L), V5 = c(2L, 10L, 16L, 40L, 1L, 8L), V6 = c(4L, 
0L, 9L, 22L, 1L, 7L), V7 = c(6L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 0L, 6L), V8 = c(2L, 
17L, 16L, 24L, 2L, 1L), V9 = c(3L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 0L, 4L), V10 = c(2L, 
11L, 5L, 11L, 2L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Finally, I found two ways of doing this. However for both, I get an error stating singular gradient.

```
#Way I
x=1:10
Mfrq.df.2_long <- pivot_longer(Mfrq.df.2, matches("V\\d{1,2}"), names_to = NULL, values_to = "Value")

Mfrq.df.2_long %>% 
group_by(User.ID) %>% 
mutate(fit = nls(Value ~ A * exp(-k * x), start = c(A =2, k = 0.01)) %>% list())
```

```
#Way2
L1 = c()
for (i in unique(Mfrq.df.2$User.ID)) {L1[[as.character(i)]]=seq(1,10)}
length(L1) #520 users
dput(head(L1))

list(`37593` = 1:10, `38643` = 1:10, `49433` = 1:10, `60403` = 1:10, 
    `70923` = 1:10, `85363` = 1:10)
```

```
#Way 2 Continue
L2=list.ids.RecSOC.2
length(L2) #520 users
dput(head(L2))

list(`37593` = c(9L, 10L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 2L), `38643` = c(3L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 0L, 8L, 17L, 20L, 11L), `49433` = c(4L, 29L, 
17L, 16L, 16L, 9L, 9L, 16L, 7L, 5L), `60403` = c(80L, 113L, 77L, 
47L, 40L, 22L, 8L, 24L, 30L, 11L), `70923` = c(19L, 21L, 7L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L), `85363` = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 
7L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 3L))
```

```
#Way 2 Continue    
control=nls.control(maxiter=1000)
res <- mapply(function(x,y){
  nls(y~A*(exp(-k*x)),
      start=list(A=100, k=0.01), control=control,
      trace= TRUE, data=data.frame(x, y))},L1,L2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

To the best of my understanding, it has something to do with the starting values. I find it hard to find starting values that would work for all 520. Especially knowing not all of them are following the defined curve. I still need all 520 coefficients (A&k) to do my further analyses.

Any recommendations? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The starting values are very important with `nls()` so you need to spend some time getting them right. First let's extract the first group:

```
Value <- unlist(Mfrq.df.2_long[Mfrq.df.2_long$User.ID==37593, "Value"])
x <- 1:10
plot(x, Value)
```

This plot shows declining values from about 10 to 2 on the Y axis as the x values range from 1 to 10. What do your starting values look like on this plot?

```
Y <- 2 * exp(.01 * x)
lines(x, Y)
```

A very slightly increasing value from 2 to 2.2 over the range of x. Clearly the value inside `exp()` must be negative and greater than .01 since the decline is much greater than your starting values and the starting value for A should be more like 10:

```
Y <- 10 * exp(-.1 * x)
lines(x, Y, col="red")
```

This is much better. Now `nls()`:

```
# fit = nls(Value ~ A * exp(k * x), start = c(A = 10, k = -.1))
# fit
# Nonlinear regression model
#   model: Value ~ A * exp(k * x)
#    data: parent.frame()
#       A       k 
# 10.8628 -0.1901 
#  residual sum-of-squares: 33.66
# 
# Number of iterations to convergence: 7 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 9.325e-06
```

Plotting the result:

```
xfit <- seq(1, 10, by=.1)
yfit <- predict(fit, list(x=xfit))
lines(xfit, yfit, col="blue")
```

Once you get the first group to work, it should be straightforward to apply it to the rest of the groups.

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 0):

One option to estimate the coefficients is to perform a linear regression on  a transformed data set.

`y = A*exp(kx)`
can be transformed to
`ln(y) = kx + B`

```
Mfrq.df.2_long <- pivot_longer(Mfrq.df.2, matches("V\\d{1,2}"), names_to = NULL, values_to = "Value")

data <- Mfrq.df.2_long[Mfrq.df.2_long$User.ID==37593, ]
#Add the independent value to data frame
data$x <- 1:10

#fit linear model ln(y)= A*x +B
model <- lm(log(Value) ~ x, data)
#predict(model, data.frame(x))

#plot original data
plot(data$x, data$Value)
#plot linear model 
#taking the exp of the prediction since the model was to preduct ln(y)
lines(data$x, exp(predict(model, data.frame(x=1:10))), col="red")

#Extract out the coefficients A=exp(intercept) from linear model 
# And set the start values 
sA <- exp(model$coefficients[1])
sk <- model$coefficients[2]
model2 <- nls(Value ~ A * exp(k * x), data= data, start = list(A = sA, k = sk))

#plot the nls model
lines(data$x, predict(model2, data.frame(x=1:10)), col="blue")
```

[image]

*Note: the equations are slightly different be the least squares is typing to minimize the differences between different values y and ln(y).*